# jquery compare 100 and 7 and get that 7>100

Tags: jquery

example is here http://jsfiddle.net/rigaconnect/9wL5z/

Here html

```
<input type="text" id="hdn_amnt_main_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast" value='100' readonly >

<input type="text" id="hdn_all_ttls_for_blw_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast" value='7'>
```

and here jquery

```
var hdn_amnt_main_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast = $('#hdn_amnt_main_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast').val();
var hdn_all_ttls_for_blw_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast = $('#hdn_all_ttls_for_blw_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast').val();

if ( hdn_all_ttls_for_blw_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast > hdn_amnt_main_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast ) {

alert ( hdn_all_ttls_for_blw_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast + '>' + hdn_amnt_main_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast ) ;

}

if ( hdn_all_ttls_for_blw_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast < hdn_amnt_main_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast ) {

alert ( hdn_all_ttls_for_blw_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast + '<' + hdn_amnt_main_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast ) ;

}
```

and get that 7 is higher than 100

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Your code is really unclear due to the variable names. But I guess it's because you're comparing strings...

Comment: Use `parseInt(strValue, 10)`

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, I see that very difficult to read. I have 12 variations of input fields (like, debit_of_debtor_debt_asset, credit_of_debtor_debt_asset and so on). I have to name the fields somehow. At the moment this is the way I choose how to name them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.val()` function gives you string. Hence you need to convert string value into appropriate one.

You need to use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) if you want to perform comparison operation on **floating point number**.

You need to use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) if you want to perform comparison operation on **integers**.

Here in example I have used `parseInt`.

```
var hdn_amnt_main_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast = $('#hdn_amnt_main_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast').val();
var hdn_all_ttls_for_blw_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast = $('#hdn_all_ttls_for_blw_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast').val();

//Convert string value to intgers
hdn_amnt_main_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast = parseInt(hdn_amnt_main_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast,10);
hdn_all_ttls_for_blw_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast = parseInt(hdn_all_ttls_for_blw_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast,10);


if (hdn_all_ttls_for_blw_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast > hdn_amnt_main_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast) {
    alert(hdn_all_ttls_for_blw_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast + '>' + hdn_amnt_main_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast);
}
if (hdn_all_ttls_for_blw_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast < hdn_amnt_main_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast) {
    alert(hdn_all_ttls_for_blw_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast + '<' + hdn_amnt_main_r_dt_of_dtr_d_ast);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/K4xW8/)

Answer (score 2):

`.val()` returns strings (as input text values are strings), and unless you type cast the values to integers, you might get that "7" is indeed greater than "100".

Here is the integer version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/9wL5z/2/

> What is wrong with the code?

Variable names.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @JanDvorak I generally agree, but here the link was more like a bonus - the real answer was that it was comparing strings instead of integers, and that if you want the expected results, you should type cast the values. The link kind of just proves that, but it's not that important, right?

Comment: Still, wouldn't it be beneficial to include the relevant part of the fiddle into the answer?